# Why is my LaTeX mathematical expression not rendered by GitHub Markdown

Tags: github, markdown, mathjax

I am trying to write a mathematical expression in GitHub README.md file. The expression is the following:
$$ \int_{-3}^{3} \int_{-3}^{3} x^2 + y^3 dxdy $$.

VS Code Markdown preview displays this expression normally with mathematical symbols. However, when I commit the change GitHub just shows this as a regular text. From what I know GitHub should support LaTeX and TeX math syntax. What is the issue here then?

Comment: The repository home page at https://github.com/userName/repName will automatically render your md and show you the expression correctly. However, editing the md is still just a text md document. If you want to link the repo we might be able to see if something else is wrong.

Comment: It works for me. Maybe you have to remove the spaces after and before $$.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent that actually works, thanks! Feel free to write it as an answer, I'll mark it as an answer and upvote it.